# Bios и настройки

Tags: netbios

Доброго времени суток ! Помогите раскрыть  второе ядро на проце амд-140 при материнке га-м720-ус3 .Весия прошивки биос ф6

Answer (score 1):

А зачем? Оно там всё равно работать не будет! Потому, что AMD Sempron 140 - это выбраковка производства AMD Athlon II X2, с одним нерабочим ядром.